# angularjs looping logic, forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach

I have an object that looks like this. Basically what I need is to loop through the filterNameList array and pull out the first value in each of the objects that belong to the filterNameList, it will always be the [0] value. Having some trouble getting these extracted out to display on the page.

```
acceptableFlag: "True"
filterNameList: Array[5]
    0: Array[2]
        0: "Asia"
        1: 20000
    1: Array[2]
        0: "China"
        1: 20001
    2: Array[2]
        0: "Beijing"
        1: 50000
reportId: 48
reportName: "Multiple"
```

Would the following function work?

```
function filterLabel(data){
    angular.forEach(data, function(obj, i){
        angular.forEach(obj, function(filterNameList, i){
            if (filterNameList.filterNameList == 20000){
                filterNameList.filterLabel = "Region"
            }
        })
    })
 };
```

Comment: Why do you use angular.forEach as opposed to `data.filterNameList.forEach(function(nameList, i) {})`

Comment: throughout other places in the code i've seen angular.forEach being used, so I adopted it also

Answer (score 3):

`obj` is an array as well. You'll either have to nest a loop, or do a static index value.

```
if(obj[1] == 20000){
    obj.regionName = "Region"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning property to an Array object is not a good way of doing this.
You can do something like

```
filterNameList.forEach(function(obj, i){
   if(obj[1] == 20000){
        obj.push("Region")
    }
   else if (obj[1] == 20001){
       obj.push('Country');
   }
   else if (obj[1] == 50000){
       obj.push('City');
   }

});
```

Comment: so would it be like this:

    function filterLabel(data.filterNameList){
        filterNameList.forEach(function(obj, i){
          if....
    }
}

Comment: Right.. after this your sub arrays will contain 3 items each

Comment: I am getting an error, saying "Not a function / got undefined"

Comment: Maybe there is a typo or filterNamesList is undefined

Comment: ok thanks, i got it fixed, but I actually edited the question above